# Data not showing with the Timestamp Values : Highcharts

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, timestamp

So What I am doing is that I am taking timestamp data as X axis and the values as Y-axis.

but the problem arises is that the data is not displaying on the chart althogh the timestamp values are being displayed in the console, but not displaying on chart.

the data values are as follows:

```
 var countArray = ["2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.232000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.233000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.234000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.235000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.236000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.237000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.238000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.239000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.240000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.241000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.242000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.243000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.244000"]; //X-axis Values

 var numArray = [2,5,3,6,4,6,3,6,3,6,3,7,3,6,3,5,3,5,6,3]  ; // Y-axis Values
```

Here is the Fiddle That I am trying.

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/wq4na5fy/

the main problem is that the data is not displaying as per the values above

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `shift` argument in the `addPoint` method to `true`, which, combined with an empty data array, causes that points do not appear.

```
if (x > 1000) {
    series.addPoint([x, y], true, false, false);
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xhok1d6e/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: But I want to shift the data after particular points .
like the example below.
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

Comment: Hi @Okeyy, So you should set the correct value in the `if` statement: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jfmqv3rt/

Comment: Okeyy. I am able to get the values that I needed by updating the fiddle in this manner. 
https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/L3k5pseg/

Comment: but the problem is that when the large data points are rendering as 100 points in one second. then the x Axis labels are not having shifting animation. the points in the x-Axis are just updating. rather than shifting to the left side

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/87w9k4e2/

here you can see . the X-axis labels are not having moving animation towards left side. the no.'s are just updating... on the place they are

Comment: It happens only when I use xAxis type = category. On type: `datetime` it works fine.

but I need category type

Comment: Unfortunately Highcharts does not support an animation of labels in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable tooltip in highcharts option like below:

```
tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
    },
```

The tooltip's content is rendered from a subset of HTML.

---

- [Highcharts Tooltip document](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip)
- [Highcharts Tooltip API Reference](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip)